# Cross browser Server-sent Events, or alternative, including Microsoft browsers

Tags: server-sent-events, server-push

According to [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=server-sent%20events), the MS IE & Edge browsers do not support [Server-sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events).

Is there a workaround?

Or an fully cross browser alternative which is as simple (which [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) do not seem to be (and, in any case, I prefer to stick to HTTP and not have multiple simultaneous protocols complicating things))?

I want AngularJs clients to be able to subscribe & unsubscribe PHP server pushed JSON data, with multiple clients being able to subscribe to the same data and only a single server action being necessary to push it, preferably without knowing to whom to push it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft's stubbornness over SSE is quite incredible, especially as implementing it is really just a layer over `XMLHttpRequest2`, the standard is short, there has been a wonderful O'Reilly book about it out for 3 years, and there are at least two open source implementations to take inspiration from.

Anyway, the recommended technique to get compatibility back to IE8 is to create a hidden iframe, and then keep polling its inner source, and just return anything that is new there:

```
iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "abc_stream.php");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

If you only need to support back to IE10, you can use an `XMLHttpRequest2` object, and listen to the `readyState==3` messages:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    //Read this.responseText from the previous offset onwards
    };
var u = url;   
u += "xhr=1&t=" + (new Date().getTime());
xhr.open("GET", u);
```

These techniques need only very slight support on the back-end: if a client is connecting with real SSE, you have to set the MIME type as `text/event-stream`, but if using the xhr hack you have to set it as `text/plain`. I have it append `xhr=1` to the URL, as shown above (and the timestamp to stop it being cached).

The xhr technique will work on all browsers where SSE works, if you did want to go for a single solution. It's one downside is that the full data being sent is building up in memory. (My suggestion is to auto-reconnect whenever the `responseText` is over 64KB, or something like that.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of EventSource polyfills for MSIE:

https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js

https://github.com/amvtek/EventSource

One of them (don't remember which) displays an annoying Alert message periodically, so you will probably have to edit the code and remove them.

You can find here an example of usage:

https://github.com/mariomac/jeasse/blob/master/examples/chat-servlet3/src/main/resources/static/index.html